# Python pip installation error exception

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip

Starting up to learn python and get this error while trying to run any installation from pip:

```
C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts>pip3.6.exe install pyperclip

Collecting pyperclip

  Using cached pyperclip-1.6.0.tar.gz

Installing collected packages: pyperclip

  Running setup.py install for pyperclip ... error

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 89: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,

  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs

  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,

  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())

  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 89: invalid continuation byte
```